# Recover broken window manager

Tags: 12.04, unity

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit

I noticed that "compiz" was eating 40% of one of my CPUs and wanted to find its configuration. After not being able to find anything in the "Settings" with words compiz or similar (I'm used to 11.04 where I had 3 settings for fanciness of animations etc) I started googling. Most suggestions say to do this:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz
```

or

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
```

I did the -1 action and my Unity closed. Restarting the computer does not bring any window manager back up. I get desktop with 2 icons, and no window manager.

How can I solve this?

P.S
Shortcuts don't work. Alt-F2 does nothing, single tap on Alt, Ctrl, Super does nothing. To open a terminal I have to open a Desktop folder icon, then search for `gnome-terminal` in `/usr/bin` and open it that way. All windows that open up cannot be resized etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up a terminal by browsing to `/usr/share/applications`in your file manager and double-clicking `gnome-terminal.desktop`. Now, run `unity --reset`.

Comment: Thank you! After running that command my terminal froze, but resetting the desktop via Alt+Prnt+k finalized this.

Comment: The `--reset` switch is now depreciated, at least in 14.04. Is there an alternative please?

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem in 14.10 . 
I solved it by deleting my `~/.config/dconf/user`  and `~/.cache/compizconfig-1`. It worked out for me, in case if it doesn't work out for you try installing a different window manager(in my case I had `cinnamon` and was able to use it smoothly even when I had problems in default window manager).